# How to set/assign my own IDs to product I insert in WooCommerce with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I know that when I:

```
wp_insert_post
```

for each product, each entry get its own ID in database by default. But the case is that I want to assign my OWN IDs in order to be able to check product stock availability to a local database that uses those same IDs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest not use custom ID because it might hamper the internal functioning of wordpress.

```
You can use add_post_meta() and get_post_meta()
```

to store your custom Ids.